# Launching URL in ios

Tags: ios

I have a method in my java webservice that takes parameter and run a sql query to update the database. The parameters are of course insert from iphone to the URL and when url execute it will call the webservice method to update the database.
My question is, how to execute a URL in ios but not open safari or anything else.here is the code:

```
-(void)updateInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Updating Profile" message:@"Your data have been saved." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert setTag:02];
    [alert show];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    GlobalObjects *global = [[GlobalObjects alloc]init];
    NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/profile/login/update/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@",global.domain,self.user, self.firstName.text,self.address.text,self.city.text,self.country.text,self.zipCode.text,self.phone.text];

    if (alertView.tag == 02 && buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        // The URL execution method should come here.

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `NSURLConnection`. Or consider the AFNetworking library.

Comment: I have looked in that too. but could not figure out how exactly use that. Can you post an example please.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the web. What kind of searches have you been running.

Comment: I am looking for running url without opening safari or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolute minimum (and not good practice) NSURLConnection example:

```
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
    // Parse data here
}
```

You should really use the asynchronous version so as not to block the main thread. Check [this](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/).

Comment: Thanks , but there is no data to parse. I am updating the database just by running the url in the browser and the data are in the url. I just need to somehow open the url without it open safari or anything else.

Comment: That's fine, this will do that. You can just ignore / discard any data. You can also check the http response code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. But now the issue is when user insert name and lastname with space in between, I will get bad URL error. any help for that ?

Comment: I found it. I changed it to [nameField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].

Comment: Good stuff. P.s. Please accept answers that are correct / up vote answers that helped.